# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test results Interpretation-significance

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I want to use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check how these two distribution at each bin are matching.

I took implementation of KS-TEST from here
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html

Comparing two distributions of each bin using p-value.

[image: Comparison of distribution using box plot and K-S Test]
[image]

The P-value seems to be sensitive to outliers, Can anyone help me on how to interpret these results ?

Comment: It should be sensitive to observations at the extremes ("outliers" as far as I can discern what you mean by the term), since they indicate a difference in distribution. The more common complaint is not that this test is sensitive to the tail, but that it's *not sensitive enough* to differences in the tail. There are many posts on site discussing the meaning of p-values. Can you explain your difficulty with interpreting a p-value in this case?

Comment: Comparing the distributions of each bin? Binning tends to be discouraged. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Glen_b If we observe in first image p value for bin 1,2,5 & 9 is almost 1, but for bin 4,6 &7 the p-value is zero & In second image for bin 3 it shows higher p value but for bin 4 it shows less P-value now how to interpret these results because bin 3 and bin 4 quartiles are almost similar to each other still there is difference in the p-value.

Comment: @Dave Sorry for name 'bin' here, they can be referred as category where in each category two distributions are compared.

Comment: You can't see most of the data in a boxplot. If by "interpret" you actually mean "how do I tell where the differences in distribution are?" you need a better display. Specifically, since the test compares ecdfs, that would be the obvious thing to display for each thing you compare.